# Кириллические символы в формате \u android

Tags: java, android, строки, unicode

Здравствуйте, вопрос вот в чем: 
есть EditText, из которого я получаю строку, в которой могут быть кириллические символы.
Как мне преобразовать эту строку в escape-последовательность с \u-кодами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html)

```
String escapedString=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("Привет");
```

Добавление в проект:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
```

---

**UPD**

Класс был перемещен из пакета `commons.lang3` в `commons.text`

Добавление в проект:

```
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'
```

Сам импорт

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. Может вы еще знаете, как эту строку в JSON передать так, чтобы получалось не :\\u043F\\u0440\\u0438\\u0432\\u0435\\u0442, а с одинарными слешами?

Comment: Оформляйте вопрос согласно правилам стэка